# I see two commands at startup in centos 7

Tags: boot, centos, bootloader, centos-7

At startup I realize that it loads the command twice ...
Boot ... Assembly ... Grub ... And all the add-ons ...
As if I had two systems at the same time.
I do not think this is normal ...

This did not significantly change my startup time ...
But I have crashes, after long periods of use ...
even with Swap activated ...

I wonder if I can have a phantom system working ...

I use Centos 7 on my Desktop and not the server ...

Comment: What do you mean by "loads the command twice"? What are you referring to as "assembly […] and all the add-ons"?

Comment: Inglês = at startup. After a while this system became long. We do not know for sure. Pnenso ... Could it be MV Box? and / or installation of x86 and x64bits ... Or p4og4qmqw and repositories with different commands ... It is a maybe ... I can not say that I do not understand ... Maybe it is so many programs installed ... But we stayed in maybe. ... In doubt ... Expecting some reasonable and coherent explanation ... For this error ... (
-------------------
------------------------------